# MongoDB backup -> tar -> gz -> gpg

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, ubuntu

I have a MongoDB server and I am using `mongodump` command to create backup. I run command `mongodump --out ./mongo-backup` then `tar -czf ./mongo-backup.tar.gz ./mongo-backup` then `gpg --encrypt ./mongo-backup.tar.gz > ./mongo-backup.tar.gz.gpg` and send this file to backup server.

My MongoDB database has **20GB** with MongoDB `show dbs` command, MongoDB `mongodump` backup directory has only **3.8GB**, MongoDB gzipped-tarball has only **118MB** and my `gpg` file has only **119MB** in size.

**How is this possible to reduce 20GB database to 119MB file? Is it fault tolerant?**

I tried to create new server ( clone of production ), enabled firewall to ensure that noone could connect and run this backup procedure. I create fresh new server and import data and there are some differences:

I ran same command from mongo shell `use db1; db.db1_collection1.count();` and `use db2; db.db2_collection1.count();` and results are:

- 807843 vs. 807831 ( *db1.collection1 source server* vs. *db1.collection1 restored server* )
- 3044401 vs. 3044284 ( *db2.collection1 source server* vs. *db2.collection1 restored server* )

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using and what type of deployment are you backing up (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster)?

Comment: @Stennie I am using MongoDB 3.3 standalone.

Comment: 3,3 would be a development release .. do you actually mean 3.4.x? Can you check with `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell? Are you using the default storage engine (WiredTiger)?

Comment: @Stennie sorry for bad version in reply ... correct version is `db version v3.2.11`

Comment: Are you using MMAP or WiredTiger storage engine?

Comment: @Stennie storage engine is WiredTiger

Comment: My theory on the large difference in storage was that you were using a replica set (with preallocated storage set aside for the oplog) and/or the MMAP storage engine (which does not compress data). Since neither of those apply, this may just be excessive storage fragmentation. Last two questions: can you post a link to a gist/pastebin with the output of `show dbs` and `db.stats()` for the database with the largest storage size?

Comment: I make dump and restore for save some space. These are actual stats after restore. I dont have stats before restore.

switched to db dtb
> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "dtb",
        "collections" : 5,
        "objects" : 7988405,
        "avgObjSize" : 1108.7155407118191,
        "dataSize" : 8856868769,
        "storageSize" : 3105005568,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 29,
        "indexSize" : 1383956480,
        "ok" : 1
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have validated the counts and size of documents/collections in your restored data, this scenario is possible although atypical in the ratios described.

> My MongoDB database has **20GB** with MongoDB `show dbs` command

This shows you the size of files on disk, including preallocated space that exists from deletion of previous data. Preallocated space is available for reuse, but some MongoDB storage engines are more efficient than others.

> MongoDB `mongodump`backup directory has only **3.8GB**

The `mongodump` tool (as at v3.2.11, which you mention using) exports an uncompressed copy of your data unless you specify the `--gzip` option. This total should represent your actual data size but does not include storage used for indexes. The index definitions are exported by `mongodump` and the indexes will be rebuilt when the dump is reloaded via `mongorestore`.

With WiredTiger the uncompressed `mongodump` output is typically larger than the size of files on disk, which are compressed by default. For future backups I would consider using `mongodump`'s built-in [archiving and compression options](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools) to save yourself an extra step.

Since your `mongodump` output is significantly smaller than the storage size, your data files are either highly fragmented or there is some other data that you have not accounted for such as indexes or data in the `local` database. For example, if you have previously initialised this server as a replica set member the `local` database would contain a large preallocated [replication oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) which will not be exported by `mongodump`.

You can potentially reclaim excessive unused space by running the [`compact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/) command for a WiredTiger collection. However, there is an important caveat: running `compact` on a collection will block operations for the database being operated on so this should only be used during scheduled maintenance periods.

> MongoDB gzipped-tarball has only **118MB** and my `gpg` file has only **119MB** in size.

Since `mongodump` output is uncompressed by default, compressing can make a significant difference depending on your data. However, 3.8GB to 119MB seems unreasonably good unless there is something special about your data (large number of small collections? repetitive data?). I would double check that your restored data matches the original in terms of collection counts, document counts, data size, and indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is much clear now. How can I "double check" my data please? I used only `show dbs;` output and `db.collections.count();`.

Comment: I prefer to use gzip after backup because on another Mongo server it slows down backup process. I need to minimalize time while `mongodump` is accessing db because in backup time I stopped all write operations ( processes ) from webserver. When dump is completed on disk, I dont care about time for gzip+tar and gpg. I start all processes right after `mongodump` finish.

Comment: @mimosvk There is no prescriptive approach to compare restored data with the original, but you could start with the before vs after counts for databases, collections, and indexes. In your description you mention some collection counts differing slightly on source versus restored server. That would be expected if you are running `mongodump` against an active MongoDB deployment; updates that happen while the `mongodump` is running may not be captured in the output. With a replica set deployment you could run `mongodump --oplog`  to capture writes that happen during the `mongodump` operation.

Comment: @mimosvk If collection counts are identical, a more time-consuming way to verify data in key collections would be to use the [`dbHash`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbHash/) command. This command creates `md5` checksums for all documents in the specified collection(s). Note: `dbHash` values will only match if all documents in the collection are identical, including ordering of fields within the BSON documents. The `dbHash` calculation only considers documents, so index definitions and collection metadata may differ.